# Argument for setting the reference group to the biggest group in linear regression

Tags: r

Is there, either for the lm() function or for some other function for linear regression, an **argument** such that the reference group can be set to **always** be the biggest group rather than the alphabetical/numerical default in lm()?

As this's often done in stats, I'm thinking I somehow keep missing it when I search the documentation or that I'm looking in the wrong places. Any help would be appreciated!

Below, even when in a UDF, is what I'd like **NOT** **to have to keep doing**.

```
mtcars # load dataset 
mtcars <- mtcars[1:31, ]  # remove a now so that there is a single biggest group
lm(mpg ~ gear+carb+disp, data = mtcars ) # carb's group 1 is the reference by default 
mtcars$carb <- as.factor(mtcars$carb) 
mtcars <- within(mtcars, carb <- relevel(carb, ref = "4")) # set carb's group 4 as the reference
lm(mpg ~ gear+carb+disp, data = mtcars )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is a built-in function to do that but it's not that difficult to write one.

```
largest_ref <- function(DF, col){
    DF[[col]] <- factor(DF[[col]])
    tbl <- table(DF[[col]])
    largest <- names(tbl)[which.max(tbl)]
    DF[[col]] <- relevel(DF[[col]], ref = largest)
    DF
}
```

Now I will reload the test dataset and change a copy of it. Then run regressions on both datasets, the one releveled by your code and the one releveled by the function above.

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars <- mtcars[1:31, ]
mtc <- mtcars

mtcars$carb <- as.factor(mtcars$carb) 
mtcars <- within(mtcars, carb <- relevel(carb, ref = "4")) # set carb's group 4 as the reference
fit1 <- lm(mpg ~ gear + carb + disp, data = mtcars) 

mtc <- largest_ref(mtc, "carb")
fit2 <- lm(mpg ~ gear + carb + disp, data = mtc) 

identical(coef(fit1), coef(fit2))
#[1] TRUE
```

As you can see, the results are the same. You can further see it with (output omited).

```
summary(fit1)
summary(fit2)
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like `lm` has any option for this, but you can just create a wrapper function to change the levels of a factor accounting to frequeuncy, then use that in the formula.

```
big.ref <- function(x) {
  if(!is.factor(x)) x<-factor(x)
  counts <- sort(table(x), decreasing = TRUE)
  relevel(x, ref=names(counts)[1])
}
lm(mpg ~ gear + big.ref(carb) + disp, data = mtcars )
```